# Generating Function for a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

If $P(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ then I have to show that there is a polynomial $h_p(x)$ of degree $\leq (d-1)$ such that $$\sum_{n\geq 0} P(n)x^{n} = \frac{h_p(x)}{(1-x)^{d+1}}.$$

I have no idea where to begin. There is a hint which says use the generating function for the polynomial. Now what is a generating function for any polynomial ? 
Any helpful thought on the problem will be highly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you solve it for $P(n) = 1$? What about $P(n)=n$, $P(n) = n^2$? Then generalize.

Comment: In case $P(n) = 1,$ then what about the degree of $h_p(x) ?$ I'm confused. Also by solving you mean to find $h_p(x)$ right ?

Comment: I solved for $h_p(x)$ and for $P(n)=1$ I have $h_p(x) = 1$ for $P(n) = n$ I have $h_p(x) =x$ but for $P(n) =n^{2}$ I didn't get any form. Any help

Comment: Your examples already show that $\deg h_p \le d-1$ cannot be right, it should be $\deg h_p \le d$

Comment: Yes it seems that degree of $h_p(x)$ have to be less than or equal to $d$ but how to solve it then ? I can't find any suitable form for $P(n) = n^2$

Comment: Update your question and show what you have so far. Then we’ll help to continue.